# Need to find/highlight non occurences between 2 columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

So I have 2 columns:

Column A: 711 rows

10.35.6.0/24
10.132.42.0/24  
10.35.7.0/24 
10.142.224.0/24 
10.142.208.0/24 
10.35.8.0/24 
10.134.224.0/24 
10.134.20.0/24 
10.134.240.0/24

Column C: 2337 rows

10.35.6.0/24
10.132.42.0/24
10.143.26.0/24
10.143.30.0/24
10.143.31.0/24
10.143.32.0/24
10.35.7.0/24
10.143.35.0/24
10.143.44.0/24

What I need is a column B that has the values of column C that do NOT occur in column A.
In this example, column B should contain the values:

10.143.26.0/24
10.143.30.0/24
10.143.31.0/24
10.143.32.0/24
10.143.35.0/24
10.143.44.0/24

So it should have (2337 -711 = 1626) rows. Is there a way to do this in MS Excel?

Comment: this is a site for programming questions. Since you have not provided any code with your question people are going to assume you have not tried anything and want someone to do this for you. that's off-topic for here

Comment: @pnuts poor question with no research deserve to be downvoted and closed. wouldn't you agree this has nothing to do with programming? It's seeking general Excel help which is IMO more suitable on SuperUser than SO. Hover over the Excel tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(C1,A:A,0)>0,"",),C1)
```

copied down to suit.

The `copied down to suit` part may technically not be a loop but is very similar in nature (in so far as a ‘process’ is repeatedly applied to different data up to a given end condition – ie when ‘suit’ ends).

=IF is a condition substantially the same as the If,…Then construct.

=MATCH has an untold amount of code underlying it – even if proprietary (thankfully provided by M$ rather than laboriously put together by a user).  VBA does not become "not programming" just because it uses functions.

Cells are referenced RC, as is an option in VBA.

The syntax can be critical, as in other programming.

The formula takes inputs and (hopefully!) produces outputs – just as in other programming.

Comment: The output was generated with a Python script so there is the scripting/programming language @me how was looking for.

I edited your answer to '=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2;$C$2:$C$2238;0)>0;"";);C2)' and it worked! Many thanks for that.

My Excel 'skills' are very very limited and I tried to google it but  that didn't result in much.

Comment: Do you need anymore details to know what I want to achieve in Excel?
Giving the code of the script or even mentioning it wouldn't change a thing.

I don't know what belongs where so I posted this question in the hope of finding a fast answer and I did. I'm not here to start an internet riot :D

So I apreciate the effort you've put in to this and providing the answer to me.